# Idiom - "To put the hurt on"

Tags: etymology, idioms, idiom-meaning

I heard the idiom "put the hurt on" a lot growing up and I have a rough feeling of what it means but I'm not quite sure how to boil down the meaning to something I can explain to someone else.

A good example of the idiom being used in context is: https://youtu.be/NMV5wwzLVSY?t=62

My rough understanding is that it means something along the lines of "did someone a disservice but because they deserved it" but maybe someone knows more about the etymology of the phrase and can help clarify it.

Comment: My understanding of the idiom (which I'd agree is not extensive) does not include the implication that the "hurt" is "deserved".  Rather it's a form of coercion or retaliation.  And the original implication of the term (as implied in gangster movies, at least) was that the "hurt" would be literal -- a beating perhaps.  (Though it has of course come to be used in a figurative sense.)  When you consider that it originally meant to physically abuse, the etymology should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to M-W  it is an AmE informal expression

***[Put the/a hurt on](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/hurt)***:

> - to injure or damage (someone or something):
>
>   - If we adopt a more aggressive strategy, we can really put the hurt on our competitors.
>   - They really put a hurt on him. [=hurt/injured him very badly]

The Concise [New Partridge](https://books.google.it/books?id=GIuEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA349&dq=%22put%20the%20hurt%20on%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi74bCayKPJAhULWxQKHX9dDO0Q6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%22put%20the%20hurt%20on%22&f=false) of Slang and Unconventional English says it is also a UK saying which means:

> - inflict pain on

According to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20a%20hurt%20on%2Cput%20the%20hurt%20on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20a%20hurt%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20the%20hurt%20on%3B%2Cc0)***  it appears to be mainly an AmE expression which has been used from the mid 60's.

There are a few example usages dated earlier, before it became a set phrase:

> - Mabel, go in the cellar and get me a club so I can put a hurt on her head and make it bleed."  from "The Broom Behind the Door" [1949](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZJtsAAAAMAAJ&q=%22put%20a%20hurt%20on%22&dq=%22put%20a%20hurt%20on%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizgunj0KPJAhXFRhQKHTZCC3kQ6AEIHzAA).
> - Taid said, " Never put a hurt on a child," and he looked at me more gravely than he ever had before. And Nain said, " This is the way I brought up Emyr." from "Three Bear Witness". [1952](https://books.google.it/books?id=T2xAAQAAIAAJ&q=%22put%20a%20hurt%20on%22&dq=%22put%20a%20hurt%20on%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNh7zz0aPJAhUK1RQKHSapDhsQ6AEIHzAA)

Answer (score 1):

"**Put the hurt on** someone" means to hurt them.  Your link takes us to a performance of the song "Santa **Put the Hurt on** You" by Benny Grunch.  There's no date given for the song, but Benny and his group was an act from the 1990s.  I can give an earlier (and musical cite) from 1962 -- "[She **Put the Hurt on** Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTXrsB0Hn60)" by Prince LaLa. (The copyright is the year before.)

There's a template here that makes the phrase understandable.  "Putting" a noun can mean the same thing as the verb related to that noun.

"Put the *question* to" means to *question*.
"Put *hands* on" means to *hand*le or man*hand*le.
"Put the *onus* on" means to *burden*